# How to fix ASP GridView bug with alternating and hidden rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I've got a grid where I specify row colors for the odd and even rows:

```
    <asp:GridView ...>
        <RowStyle CssClass="oddRow" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="evenRow" />
        ...
    </asp:GridView>
```

and this looks like this:

[image]

Notice how rows 2 and 3 are the same color.  This is because of some code in the `RowDataBound` event that does this:

```
If {some_condition} Then
  e.Row.Visible = False
End If
```

So what's happening is that the third row is being hidden, but the grid is rendering rows 2 and 4 with the `evenRow` style, because they are even numbered rows **before hiding row 3**, and that is why the colors don't alternate:

[image]

So, is there a way to tell the GridView to render the odd/even styles based on the **visible** rows, not the original rows?  Or do I have to rearchitect everything to filter the data before binding to the grid in the first place?  (I think this would be the cleaner approach, but this is some otherwise working legacy code and I'm trying to fix the bug with a minimum of disruption.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Grid is using a `SqlDataSource`, which has filtering built in.  It looks like this:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ...
        FilterExpression="{0} = True OR ({0} = False AND Field1 = Value1 AND Field2 <> Value2)">
        <SelectParameters>
           ...
        </SelectParameters>
        <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="MyCheckBox" Name="ShowAll" PropertyName="Checked"  DefaultValue="False" />
        </FilterParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I think this wouldn't be flexible enough for all scenarios, but it was enough for my situation, so I used this and now the rows color properly.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering the data makes good sense. You're asking the grid to understand which of your data is real, and which is just pretend. Don't let it ever see the filtered data, and you don't have a problem.

Comment: I think you're right, but I subsequently found a way to filter the `SqlDataSource` directly, so I'm going with that, since it's less that I have to change, and I don't want to mess with this page more than I have to.